# Multiplication with xlop

Tags: xlop

When I use the xlop package command

```
\opmul[displayintermediary=None]{453}{1001205}
```

to display the multiplication of 453 and 1001205 without the intermediary steps, pdflatex gives me errors.  This example comes straight from the xlop documentation.

Is there an easy fix?  All other xlop commands seem to work fine for me.

Comment: compiles fine on my installation  (TL2013 as of today)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get no error. Can you present a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem? It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

Please always post complete documents that show the problem.

This file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\opmul[displayintermediary=None]{453}{1001205}
\end{document}
```

works without error and shows these versions in the log

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    xlop.sty    2009/12/02 package wrapper for xlop.tex
 ***********
```

Producing

[image]